# How to Select Two tables without union and union all?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1:

```
Id  | Text      | Parent Id | Number
**************************************
101 |robber     | 201       | 1
102 |devel      | 202       |  1
103 |programmer | 203       | 3


Table 2     
Id  | TO id     | Parent Id | Number
**************************************
102 |355        | 201       | 1
104 |366        | 202       |  2
105 |377        | 203       | Null
```

I need to join two tables without using `Union` and `union All`

Out Put Like:
(Both table columns are same expect one To Id that columns add to last )

```
Id  |   Text    | Parent Id |  Number | To Id
101 |robber     | 201       |  1      |  Null
102 |devel      |  202      | 2       | null
103 |programmer |  203      |  3      |Null
102 |Null       | 201       |  1      |355
104 | Null      |   202     |  2      | 366
105 |Null       |    203     |  null  | 377
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `UNION`?

Comment: why not use union or union all?  It is doable without but not easy manners.  Are temp tables  or table variables allowed?  Union/union all would be most efficient code

Comment: am using union in my code it will show error. Because of am going to this step..

Comment: Possible to use Full Join??

Comment: Full join won't produce the output you want. Pretty much only a union will...

Comment: I think `UNION` is the way to go here.  Can you show the query which caused the errors?  There may be a simple fix.

Comment: if any other way to possible??

Comment: I mean, you could insert the values into a temporary table from both tables, then select from a temporary table, but making your UNION work is the easiest way to do it... I would follow @TimBiegeleisen's advice and post the query that produces errors.

Comment: possible to union and union All??? pls i need query

Comment: @Developer seeing your output can't this be achieved using left join or right join based upon how you choose your table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `full join`

```
select isnull(a.id,b.id) as id, 
    a.Text1,isnull(a.ParentId,b.ParentId) parentid,
    isnull(a.Number,b.Number) numm,TOid 
 from @t a 
 
 full join @t1 b on a.Id=b.Id and a.ParentId=b.ParentId
```

data

```
declare @t table (Id int,Text1 varchar(50),ParentId int, Number int) insert into @t
(Id,Text1,ParentId, Number) values
(101 ,'robber'     , 201       , 1),
(102 ,'devel'      , 202       ,  1),
(103 ,'programmer' , 203       , 3)

declare @t1 table (Id int,TOid int,ParentId int, Number int) insert into @t1
(Id,TOid,ParentId, Number) values
(102 ,355        , 201       , 1),
(104 ,366        , 202       ,  2),
(105 ,377        , 203       , Null)
```

Answer (score 1):

and for the non-union way you can use a temp table as follows

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TempTable
    END

CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    Id INT
    ,[Text] VARCHAR(20)
    ,ParentId INT
    ,Number INT
    ,ToId INT
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable (Id, [Text], ParentId, Number)
SELECT
    Id
    ,[Text]
    ,ParentId
    ,Number
FROM
    TableNameA

INSERT INTO #TempTable (Id, ToId, ParentId, Number)
SELECT
    Id
    ,ToId
    ,ParentId
    ,Number
FROM
    TableNameB


SELECT *
FROM
    #TempTable
```

I would only use this way in circumstances that I definitely want a temp table of the results or if my logic has to be broken up for some reason, very rare for the later.  There are still other ways yet but if you are not using a temp table union all should perform better than the other ways.

Comment: @Asiyana2010 thanks I missed the column shift I appreciate the asistance